# How to import csv files in Python containing badly formatted quote marks?

Tags: python, csv, import

I'm trying to load the following test.csv file:

```
R1C1    R1C2    R1C3
R2C1    R2C2    R2C3
R3C1    "R3C2   R3C3
R4C1    R4C2    R4C3
```

... Using this Python script :

```
import csv


 with open("test.csv") as f:
      for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
          print(row)
```

The result I got was the following :

```
['R1C1', 'R1C2', 'R1C3']
['R2C1', 'R2C2', 'R2C3']
['R3C1', 'R3C2\tR3C3\nR4C1\tR4C2\tR4C3\n']
```

It turns out that when Python finds a field whose first character is a quotation mark and there is no closing quotation mark, it will include all of the following content as part of the same field.

My question: What is the best approach for all rows in the file to be read properly? Please consider I'm using Python 3.8.5 and the script should be able to read huge files (2gb or more), so memory usage and performance issues should be also considered.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you're dealing with that much data, it'd be best to go in and clean it first. And if possible, fix whatever process is producing your bad data in the first place.

I haven't tested with a large file, but you may just be able to replace `"` characters as you read lines, assuming there's never a case where they're valid characters:

```py
import csv


with open("test.csv") as f:
    line_generator = (line.replace('"', '') for line in f)
    for row in csv.reader(line_generator, delimiter='\t'):
        print(row)
```

Output:

```py
['R1C1', 'R1C2', 'R1C3']
['R2C1', 'R2C2', 'R2C3']
['R3C1', 'R3C2', 'R3C3']
['R4C1', 'R4C2', 'R4C3']
```

Comment: @Borgesj were you helped by my answer?

Comment: your tip was helpful! Thanks!
I actually got to solve this replacing " by \\", and on csv.reader method I used escapechar='\\'.

line_generator = (line.replace('"', '\\"') for line in f)
row_reader = csv.reader(line_generator, delimiter='\t', escapechar='\\')

I preferred to keep the quotes to not manipulate the data, and the script worked fine!

Comment: That's great to hear! If you feel that my answer is a satisfactory solution to your problem that may benefit future readers, please consider "accepting" my answer with the check mark. That way, the question will be removed from the unanswered queue. Otherwise, please feel free to post your own answer to your question and accept it!